# WebStorm doesn't indicate TypeScript error until the file is opened

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I am using `NodeJS` with `TypeScript` in WebStorm. The problem I started experiencing recently is that it doesn't show compile time errors in *.ts  files until I open the file.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using TypeScript service, all dependent files are not sent to server on re-highlighting the current file - it would be too expensive. That's why highlighting is not updated until you open a file in editor. You can try using **Show project errors** in TypeScript tool window to see all errors:

[image]

Comment: can't seem to find this option. I am using Webstorm 2018.1

Comment: I'm also using 2018.1; and it's definitely there. Do you have Typescript toolwindow open?